# Query: Hardcoding Of Trigger New

Tags: trigger, security-review

I have wrote an trigger which works fine functionality wise but when we send our product for security review it says

> Query: Hardcoding Of Trigger New

Below is my trigger

```
trigger CostTrigger on Cost__c (after insert, after update) {
    try{
        if(trigger.isUpdate){
            CostMember__c costMember = [SELECT Id, Name FROM CostMember__c 
                                                    WHERE User__c = :trigger.old[0].OwnerId 
                                                    AND Cost__c = :trigger.new[0].Id LIMIT 1];
            if(costMember != null){
                delete costMember;
            }
        }
        User userObject = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = :trigger.new[0].OwnerId];
        CostMember__c costMember = new CostMember__c();
        costMember.Name = userObject.Name;
        costMember.Cost__c = trigger.new[0].Id;
        costMember.User__c = trigger.new[0].OwnerId;
        costMember.MemberType__c = 'Owner';
        insert costMember;
    } Catch(Exception ex){

    }
}
```

I want the first recordId whenever the trigger runs.(even if multiple records are triggering at the same time)

How can I replace trigger.new[0] and trigger.old[0]?
Please let me know if my question is not clear or something else is required from my side.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you recode the trigger so that it works whatever the set of Cost__c records is. While the current code may work when a single record is updated or in the bulk cases you currently know about, future bulk cases may break it. Also get rid of the try/catch or at a minimum justify it in a comment; “silent failures” are painful to diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks like you only need the first element always and not the complete list so you can do something like

```
Cost newCost = new Cost__c();
Cost oldCost = new Cost__c();
for(Cost__c cost : Trigger.New) {
    newCost = cost;
    break;
}
if(trigger.isUpdate){
    for(Cost__c cost : Trigger.Old) {
        oldCost = cost;
        break;
    }
}
```

Although it still better if you modify your actual code to handle bulk case as well.

So you can do

```
if(Trigger.New.size() == 1) {
  // use first element
} else {
   // use bulk processing
}
```